# How do I identify and send info to 2 different elements with the exact same info in Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, attributes, webdriver, element

I'm automating filling out a online form.  Problem is lots of the fields have the 
same attribute info. Both examples below are address lines in different sections I'm trying to send different address info but selenium keeps identifying only one element because the information is the same.  Xpath and Css isn't identifying them separately either. Any Suggestions?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span7">
<label for="AddressLine1">Street Address 1</label>
<input id="AddressLine1" class="span" type="text" value="" name="AddressLine1">
</div>

//Second area on form
<div class="span7">
<label for="AddressLine1">Street Address 1</label>
<input id="AddressLine1" class="span" type="text" value="" name="AddressLine1">
</div>
```

Comment: And each area is not a identified by a different html tag? I find it odd that everything would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath Position() in such scenarios.
Suppose if you have 10 address fields with same xpath, you can just use the below selenium type command to write address in the 6th address box.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][position()=6]")).sendKeys("Address")
```

For more options, refer to [this](http://automationtricks.blogspot.in/2010/09/how-to-use-functions-in-xpath-in.html)

Comment: This is i xpath...how do I insert the position in this?

Comment: Try this 
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="AddressLine1"][position()=1]")).sendKeys("address1")`

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"AddressLine1\"][position()=2]")).sendKeys("Check this");

Comment: I tried this driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"AddressLine1\"][position()=2]")).sendKeys("Check this");
no luck :(

Comment: This is the second address text box im trying to send keys to

Comment: why are you adding a \ before address line? can you paste the xpath you are getting directly from firebug?

Comment: //*[@id="AddressLine1"]             //the xpath

Comment: I use the \ because the " " in Address line causes errors since its driver.findelement(By.xpath("   //*[@id="AddressLine1"] ")--the quotes cause errors now it works when i use it with position 1 but with position 2 no luck

Comment: Try giving position()=0 for first text box and position()=1 for second text box.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> divs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.span7"));
```

if you want the first div

```
divs.get(0);
```

if you want the second div

```
divs.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

css=div.row-fluid > div.span7:nth-of-type(i) > #AddressLine1 -- CSS Selector

i -- Size of div which is having the class span7.

Please Let me know is the above CSS Selector is working or NOT.

Thanks!